# In R, how can I use different colors for each range in my scatterplot?

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot with R a series of 120 numbers where the first 40 are of one type, the next 40 items are of a second type and the last 40 items are of a third type.

Right now I'm just plotting it as a scatter-plot and its hard to tell the three sections apart:

```
data <- read.table("mydata.txt")
plot(data[,1])
```

[image: what I have]

Is there a way to distinguish the three sections, as in this following mockup that I made?

[image: what I want]

Comment: First step: do you have a variable containing a distinct value per group? For instance: `data$colindex = rep(1:3,each=40)`?

Comment: Right now I don't and things are defined implicitly by index. However, I'm fine with adding extra columns to my data if that will make things simpler.

Comment: You need that, to index a palette of colors, such as the one provided by `rainbow` in Mark answer. You may create your own palette `col=c("red","green","blue")[data$colindex]`  (google for 'R list of colors names' or look at `rgb` function. Finally, consider `ggplot` package and framework, you will see that doing a group-colored scatterplot is easy, cf. http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_point.html

Comment: What does the x-axis represent here, and how do you "know" where the cutoffs are between data groups?  My concern is that you are incorrectly plotting the data in the first place.  It's very unusual to have a single 'index' which spans three classes of data.  It may well be that the data should be presented as three histograms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could provide a colour vector if the data are already ordered.

```
mydata <- runif(120)
plot(mydata, col = rep(rainbow(3), each = 40))
```

`rainbow(3)` makes a colour vector of 3 colours, and `rep` with `each = 40` makes 40 copies of each.

Comment: Could this answer be adapted to the case where each group has different amounts? For example, 30,40,50 instead of 40,40,40?

Comment: I guess you could do `rainbow(3)[c(rep(1, 30), rep(2, 40), rep(3, 50))]` but that's pretty ugly. As Eric commented above, a vector describing the sections is the best way to go.

Answer (score -1):

A longer answer not as nice as the one of Mark O'Connell but has the merit to be more flexible.(I think)

```
data<-data.frame(y=seq(1,1000)+rnorm(1000,0,100),index=seq(1,1000))

data.blue<-data[data$index<200,]
data.green<-data[data$index>=200&data$index<400, ]
data.red<-data[data$index>=400&data$index<600, ]
data.purple<-data[data$index>=600&data$index<1000, ]

plot(data.blue,col='blue',xlim=c(-200,1300),ylim=c(0,1000))
points(data.green$index,data.green$y,col='green')
points(data.red$index,data.red$y,col='red')
points(data.purple$index,data.purple$y,col='purple')
```

Comment: Why duplicate data when it is not useful? Also, if you want to exploit cutpoints, simply use `cut` function.